# My hook_menu_alter() and page callback don't get triggered

Tags: taxonomy-terms, routes

This question relates to [How do I redirect a taxonomy menu item to another path?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/25613)

I followed the recommendations of Clive and wrote a hook_menu_alter to provide my callback.

```
function material_menu_taxonomy_page_callback($term) {
  dsm('Entered material menu callback');
}

function material_menu_menu_alter () {
  $items['taxonomy/term/%taxonomy_term']['page callback'] = 'material_menu_taxonomy_page_callback'; 
}
```

I placed a code line `dsm("Altering");` in the callback to see where in the process the callback is being called, but it never shows up.

I am fairly certain that I have the code correct.

- The hook has the name of the custom module.
- The callback name is correct.
- the callback is in the same file as the hook
- I have turned the module off and then on so that I can be sure that Drupal knows about `mymodule_menu_alter`
- And I have flushed the caches.

My assumption is that `mymodule_menu_alter()' should change the callback in the menu item array and that the callback will be called each time the menu item is selected. That suggests that my`dsm()` message should display at the top of the page requested by the menu.

While Clive's test indicated in his answer worked, my revisions did not. Following Clive's answer recommendations I revised the code as follows.

#### material.info file contained in modules subdirectory = sites/all/modules/Custom/material

```
name = Materials  
description = Redefine the path for materials menu
package = CR-Hub
core = 7.x
; Includes
files[] = material.module
```

#### material.module file in same subdirectory

```
function material_taxonomy_page_callback() {
  drupal_goto('taxonomy/term/1');
  // return 'Entered material menu callback';
}

function material_menu_alter(&$items) {
  // return 'Entered Material Menu Alter';
  $items['taxonomy/term/%taxonomy_term']['page callback'] = 'material_taxonomy_page_callback'; 
  return $items;
}
```

When I select any menu item neither `drupal_goto()`, or `return 'any text'` lines redirect the selected path from the menu item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't passed `$items` into the function ;)

```
function material_menu_menu_alter (&$items) {
  $items['taxonomy/term/%taxonomy_term']['page callback'] = 'material_menu_taxonomy_page_callback'; 
}
```

Without that you're not actually altering anything as `$items` doesn't exist in a global scope.

You'll also need to clear the caches again once you've made the change.

**UPDATE**

Working code that I've just verified:

material.info:

```
name = Materials  
description = Redefine the path for materials menu
package = CR-Hub
core = 7.x
; Includes
files[] = material.module
```

material.module

```
function material_taxonomy_page_callback($term) {
  // Calling drupal_goto() here will result in an infinite loop.
  // This is the page callback for pages with a URL like taxonomy/term/1 so
  // there's no need to redirect...you're already where you need to be.
  // This function is used to build up the new page content for the taxonomy page

  // As a test just output the name of the term related to this page.
  return $term->name;
}

function material_menu_alter (&$items) {
  $items['taxonomy/term/%taxonomy_term']['page callback'] = 'material_taxonomy_page_callback'; 

  // You don't need to return anything from this function as $items is passed in by reference...anything you change in that variable will be reflected in the $items var in the calling function.
}
```

Once installed if I go to any taxonomy page the content region contains just the name of the taxonomy term for that page (using `return $term->name`). If it's not working for you the only thing I can advise is to clear Drupal's caches, or check what custom/contributed modules you've got installed that might be overriding your code.

Comment: Yeah sure, pick the easy stuff! Other than that, whats wrong with it???  :)

Comment: I've just popped your code (with the slight change above) into a module called `material_menu` and it works perfectly...the only difference was I added `return 'test';` to the callback function so a page would actually be displayed. It's probably a stupid question but is the module definitely called `material_menu`, i.e. is the folder the module file is in called `material_menu`?

Comment: The module is called material_menu.  This is my first venture in hooks.   I will be adding it into a custom module for a website I am attempting to build.  The intent is that I have a taxonomy called materials and have generated a taxonomy menu for it.  The Material (280 so far) selected defines a category and a series of views in a definition will deliver subcategories (8 total) attached to tabs to deliver different types of articles relating to the material.  To do so I must redirect the path from the taxonomy path to invoke the desired views.  That's where hook_menu_alter comes in.

Comment: BTW your assistance is greatly appreciated!  Learning Drupal code feels like swallowing an elephant.  Its very helpful to have someone who knows how to cut it into bite size chunks.

Comment: I tried repeating your successful test and cannot reproduce it.  I placed my updated code in the question. I rewrote the module and it will not react to drupal_go_to or return 'text'; messages. The menu was defined using taxonomy menu.  Could that be changing the required $items [key] needed?

Comment: @Ashlar I've updated the answer, hope it helps :)

Comment: @Ashlar Clive didn't pick up the easy stuff: He picked up the more evident error in the code you shown. Until you don't fix that error, and you don't report what else didn't work in your code, Clive cannot point out what in the code should be changed.

Comment: This answer is correct: In the menu callback for test, you cannot call `drupal_goto('test')` because that would cause the same menu callback be called again, and `drupal_goto('test')` executed too.

Comment: @clive  Since I want a view to handle the page callback, could I have simply placed the view URL in the page callback's value ie.  ...['page callback'] = 'material/view'; where that url is a view path?

Comment: If you want a view to handle the page callback you can dispense with the custom code completely...just change the path of the view to `taxonomy/term/%` and it will magically work :) There's actually a view provided by Views that already overrides the taxonomy page. It's disabled by default but you can enable it and either look it at to see how it works, or simply make the changes you want to in that View.

Comment: @clive & kiamlaluno  In my updated code I also tried removing the drupal_go_to line and used the    return ('Entered material menu callback'); line, but it never shows up either.

Comment: @clive.  I realize that the view for tax terms exists.  I was simply trying to do the same thing with a URL that made more sense to a user.  Since views doesn't work with aliases.  I was pursuing this course of action. I also wanted to learn to code menu hooks, but this has turned out to be quite a learning challenge!

Comment: Views works just fine with aliases; if you install the PathAuto module you can set up a pattern for taxonomy term pages and you'll have URL aliases enabled automatically!

Comment: I misstated, a View will be called using an alias, but contextual filters do not work with the alias.  They will only respond to the real URL behind the alias - taxonomy/term/%.  Plus I am still puzzled why the hook_menu_alter does not appear to ever be called either using the return('text') or a dsm('text') line.

Comment: If you still have that taxonomy view enabled it might be overriding your efforts to do that alter. Try disabling that view, clear the caches and see if that makes a difference

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2872/discussion-between-ashlar-and-clive)

Answer (score 2):

I think what you may be missing is that the taxonomy menu item has a file set to look for the callback in the taxonomy.pages.inc

Try this:

```
$items['taxonomy/term/%taxonomy_term']['page callback'] = 'your_callback';
$items['taxonomy/term/%taxonomy_term']['file'] = '';
```

Comment: As long as `your_callback()` is in a module file, it is fine to leave the value of `$items['taxonomy/term/%taxonomy_term']['file']` as it was before, especially if that file still needs to be loaded to use one of the functions it contains.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do exactly the same thing described in Clive's answer, but the override was not working.

Finally I found out that what was preventing it from working was that I had the module Taxonomy Display enabled on the site. Disabling it was the solution to my problem.

So, you should disable any views overriding taxonomy/term/% but you should also check your enabled modules!

Hope this helps.