# How to redirect all URLs of all terms in a specific vocabulary to custom URLs

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, uri, redirection

I am a newbie to Drupal and having hard time to understand how to redirect all URLs for all terms in a specific vocabulary to custom URLs.

I have tried to use [Entity Path](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_path), but it did not work for me. By some reasons this module sets automatic alias field empty in a term edit form. This breaks Pretty Path module that I am also using.

I have also tried to implement custom hook as described [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26167/my-hook-menu-alter-and-page-callback-dont-get-triggered), but cannot understand how to make it work only for a specific vocabulary, the hook applies to all vocabularies on my site.

I would be greatly appreciate if someone can provide a step-by-step instruction to solve this issue.

**edit after I tried to get it to work via Rues**

Here is exported Rules

```
{ "rules_redirect_an_old_path_to_a_new_path" : {
    "LABEL" : "Redirect Categories Terms to Custom Path",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "ACTIVE" : false,
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "ON" : { "init" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "text_matches" : { "text" : [ "site:current-page:url" ], "match" : "existing_vocabulary_alias/[term:name]" } }
    ],
    "DO" : [ { "redirect" : { "url" : "custom_text\/custom_text\/[term:name]" } } ]
  }
}
```

Comment: What are the paths (patterns) for which you want to perform such redirect?

Comment: Pattern is as follow: Taxonmy is set to have default path in pathauto module. I want to redirect all terms in one vocabulary to http://root_directory/custom_path/custom_path/term_alias

Answer (score 1):

The [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module is your friend to implement such redirects ...

Here is the rule you'd need for it (in Rules export format, just use copy/paste it to import it in your own setup via the Rules UI):

```
{ "rules_redirect_an_old_path_to_a_new_path" : {
    "LABEL" : "Redirect an old path to a new path",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "ON" : { "init" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "text_matches" : {
          "text" : [ "site:current-page:url" ],
          "match" : "the_old_path",
          "operation" : "starts"
        }
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "Sorry, the old path (= /the_old_path) is no longer in use, you will be redirected automatically to its corresponding path (= /the_new_path)" } },
      { "redirect" : { "url" : "the_new_path" } }
    ]
  }
}
```

A few more tweaks to make it fit your exact scenario:

- change all occurences of `the_old_path` to your old path corresponding to `[term:vocabulary]/[term:name]`.
- change all occurences of `the_new_path` to your new path corresponding to `CUSTOM_WORDS/CUSTOM_WORDS/[term:name]`.

Attention (1): when applying those 2 changes above, you want to do so using the Views UI. So that you are sure that you'll use the exact Rules syntax, e.g. using "tokens" that the Rules module makes available. But also know that sometimes it's a bit tough and/or tricky to get that right.

Attention (2): it could well be that the Rules condition (with that `text_matches`) has to be replaced by something using a "regular expression" (instead of that `starts` in my sample).

Whenever such redirect actually happens, the user will also receive an informational message like so:

> *Sorry, the old path (= `/the_old_path`) is no longer in use, you will be redirected automatically to its corresponding path (= `/the_new_path`)*

If you don't want such message to appear, then just delete the line containing `drupal_message` in the exported rule above.

Comment: Thank you Pierre.Vriens. Sorry for bothering you. Can you please give an instruction for how to set an appropriate rule for taxonomy redirect. It is still hard for me to use Rules

Comment: You're not "bothering" (don't worry) ... I'd be happy to give you an exact answer if you could give me an actual example of an "old path" (to be redirected) and a "new path" (to where it should be redirected). If it applies in your case, also indicate which "patterns" such paths include, like node IDs (= nid), etc, if any. OK?

Comment: Thank you again Pierre.Vriens for being so gentle. My Old Path is set in Pathauto Module like [term:vocabulary]/[term:name]. I want to redirect to a new path like CUSTOM_WORDS/CUSTOM_WORDS/[term:name]

Comment: With your help Pierre.Vriens, Rules now redirects to CUSTOM_WORDS/CUSTOM_WORDS, however it still not adds [term:name] to the url. I think it happens because Rules is not aware of  [term:name] in the CONDITIONS of the Rules's settings. Is that correct?

Comment: Looks like you ran into what I was predicting with those "tokens" in my "attention(1)" ... give me some time to think about enhancing my answer about it. Can you maybe EXPAND your question (near the end of it) with like an "edit after I tried to get it to work via Rues", and then also insert the EXPORTED rule in it you already have so far?

Comment: Didn't know rules could do redirection, nifty!

Comment: Merci for the kudos. Rules is not just great, it's amazing.My "personal" favorite scenario for using Rules is like in my answer to the questions with id=170742 ... forget ".htaccess" ....! And of course: anything you can do only requires site building skills (no tricky, possibly hard to maintain custom (PHP) code). My only concern about using rules is to be careful about possible performance issues ... Can't wait for a D8 release of it to become available (= my prereq before upgrading any D7 site ....).