# How do I change taxonomy page callback for a specific vocabulary only?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, redirection

Following [Clive's](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/2800/clive) answer to [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/25613/how-do-i-redirect-a-taxonomy-menu-item-to-another-path), I would like to change taxonomy page callback and redirect users to another page just for a specific vocabulary.

```
function MYMODULE_taxonomy_page_callback($term) { 
  if (/* Check if the vocabulary is the one we need to implement hook to */) {
    drupal_goto('somewhere'); 
  }
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the callback is getting the taxonomy term object as argument, you can check the value in `$term->vocabulary_machine_name` to get the machine name of the vocabulary, and see if it is the one you are interested in.

```
function MYMODULE_taxonomy_page_callback($term) { 
  if ($term->vocabulary_machine_name == 'MYVOCABULARY') {
     drupal_goto('somewhere'); 
  }
  else {
    return taxonomy_term_page($term);
  }
}
```